# How do you pass an array and an object as an argument in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, react-native

**Current Code**

```js
async onPressAdd() {
  // at this moment, items is an array and shop is an object
  db.storeSale(items, shop);
}
```

In different file

```js
storeSale = async ({ items,shop }) => {
  console.log(items); // undefined
  console.log(shop);  // not object
}
```

I'm trying to pass an array and an object as an argument, but it is not working like above code.

I want receive items as an array and shop as an object.

I would appreciate it if you could give me any advices.

Comment: Your code tries to destructure the first argument. Just use `async (items, shop) =>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the type of the arguments.

You're *destructuring* your parameter list in `storeSale`, which means it's expecting a single parameter: an object with `items` and `shop` properties. But what you're passing it is two discrete arguments.

Either:

1. Pass it an object instead:

   ```
   async onPressAdd() {
     db.storeSale({items, shop})
     // −−−−−−−−−−^−−−−−−−−−−−^
   }
   ```

   and leave `storeSale` the same as you have it now, or
2. Have `storeSale` accept discrete parameters by removing the `{}`from the parameter list:

   ```
   storeSale = async (items, stop) => {
   // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^−−−−−−−−−−−^−−−− no {} here
   ```

   and leave your call to it the same as you have it now.

Answer (score 0):

storeSale is expecting an object with 
{
 items, 
 shop
}

but you give him 2 parameters instead

try 
db.storeSale({items, shop});